# Redirect STDERR in OPEN pipe comand. Perl Linux

Tags: linux, perl

The version of perl I'm restricted to is v5.10.0;

I have a script, "script1" that needs to call another script "script2."

In order to bypass the shell and avoid command line injection I am using "open" to do this in perl.

open(my $fh, "-|", "/path/to/script2", "-n", "$param") or say "failure $@";

I can not modify script2.

I need to get the output of the stderr from script2 into a variable in script1.

I got the "-|" syntax from https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html but the description there is mostly an example of how to do it and not what it is doing so I can't figure out how to redirect err to out or even at least redirect err to some other variable.

I'm hoping for something that will look similar to one of these two options:

```
# option 1)
open(my $fh, "-|", "/path/to/script2", "-n", "$param") or say "failure $@";
while($line = <$fh>) {  # stderr and stdout are both fed to $line
     print $line;
}

# option 2)
open(STDERR, "+<", $stderr);
open(my $fh, "-|", "/path/to/script2", "-n", "$param") or say "failure $@";
while($line = <$fh>) {  #stdout is fed to $line
     print $line;
}
while($line = <$stderr>) {  #stderr from script2 is fed to $line
     print $line;
}
```

Comment: Can you install additional modules? If so, look at Capture::Tiny.

Comment: See also [`IPC::Open3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) and [`IPC::Run3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using [`IPC::Run3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run3;

run3 ['script2.pl', '-n', $param], undef, \my $out, \my $err;
```

This will give you the STDERR of `script2.pl` in the variable `$err`.

From the documentation:

> **run3($cmd, $stdin, $stdout, $stderr, \%options)**
>
> All parameters after $cmd are optional.
>
> The parameters $stdin, $stdout and $stderr indicate how the child's
>   corresponding filehandle (STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, resp.) will be
>   redirected. Because the redirects come last, this allows STDOUT and
>   STDERR to default to the parent's by just not specifying them -- a
>   common use case.
>
> **$cmd**
>
> Usually $cmd will be an ARRAY reference and the child is invoked via
>
> `system @$cmd;`

Note that passing `$cmd` as an array reference will avoid running the command through the shell under the same conditions as for the [`system()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command

Comment: Can you pass `$cmd` as a list or do you need to sanitize the input?

Comment: Yes I think you can pass it as a list, exactly as for the `system` command, and the shell will not be invoked

Comment: @mob, You can pass an array ref to avoid the shell. For example, `my $cmd = [ $prog, @args ]` won't use the shell (even if `@args` is empty).

Comment: I wound up using open3 and having stderr and stdout exist in the same var, but this run3 would have worked as well.

Comment: @FredMan. If you used `open3` to capture the child's STDOUT and STDERR separately, I bet your code is buggy. Specifically, I bet you have a race condition that can lead to a deadlock. Did you use threads or IO::Select or non-blocking reads?

Comment: @ikegami I didn't capture it separately.  I set the third parameter to undef so that err and out would go to the same variable.

Comment: @FredMan , That's fine then :) Could also have used `use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote ); open(my $pipe, '-|', shell_quote($prog, @args) . " 2>&1");`

Answer (score 3):

If the objective is to capture streams one nice module is [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.46/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);

my $cmd  = '/path/to/script2';
my @args = ('-n', $param);

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
    system($cmd, @args);
};
```

You can put the command and arguments in a list, `@cmd = ('ls', '-l', './')`. If the command and arguments are lumped into a scalar the shell may get used (if there are shell metacharacters).

This portable module allows you to

> capture almost anything sent to STDOUT or STDERR, regardless of whether it comes from Perl, from XS code or from an external program.

There is also `capture_stderr` function if you only want that stream.

Note that many tools, including `system`, have a provision for bypassing the shell: pass command and/or arguments as a list. (However, if you need `STDERR` you cannot get it directly with `system` alone, without using shell redirection.)

---

If there is a possibility that `@args` would be empty this should be invoked as

```
system ( {$cmd} $cmd, @args );
```

and the shell is still avoided.  A nice way to try it out is with `$cmd = 'echo "From shell"'`. Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for noting all this in a comment.

See [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) for this use of the *indirect object* notation, which

> forces interpretation of the LIST as a multivalued list, even if there is only a single scalar in the list

and this ensures that the shell is never called.