# How to redirect output of some commands to a file but keep some in the console?

Tags: perl, stdout

I am using below perl script,

```
open (STDOUT, '>',"log.txt")|| die "ERROR: opening log.txt\n";
print "\n inside";
close (STDOUT);
print "\noutside";
```

I need string "inside" need to be printed inside log.txt. string "outside" need to be printed in the console.

But with my script string "inside" is printed inside log.txt, but string "outside" is not printed on the console.

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 2):

You [*redirect* the standard output stream](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to a file with `open STDOUT, '>', $file`.  After that there is no simple way to print to the console.

Some ways to print to both a file and the console

- Save `STDOUT` before redirecting and restore it later when needed. Again, see [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

  ```
  open SAVEOUT, ">&STDOUT"  or warn "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";
  open *STDOUT, ">", $logfile or warn "Can't redirect STDOUT to $logfile: $!";
  say "goes to file"; 
  ...
  open STDOUT, ">&SAVEOUT"  or warn "Can't reopen STDOUT: $!";  # restore
  say "goes to console";
  ```
- Print to a variable what you intend for console; use [select](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to switch the default for where prints go

  ```
  open my $fh_so, '>', \my $for_stdout;
  select $fh_so;
  say "goes to variable \$for_stdout";
  say STDOUT "goes to console";
  ...
  select STDOUT;    # make STDOUT default again
  say $for_stdout;  # goes to console (all accumulated $fh_so prints)
  ```

  With this you can reach the console by specifying `STDOUT`, otherwise you would put out all STDOUT-intended prints once you `select` back to `STDOUT`
- Print logs to a file directly, as in [Jens's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47867537/4653379)

  ```
  open my $fh_log, '>', $logfile or die "Can't open $logfile: $!";
  say $fh_log "goes to $logfile";
  say         "goes to console";
  ...
  close $fh_log;
  ```

  where the default `print` (or rather `say` above) keeps going to the console

The first two seem a little cumbersome, don't they.  I'd recommend to print logs directly to a log file, unless `STDOUT` needs to be redirected for the most of the program, or you have a compelling reason to `select` filehandles around.

For `say`, which adds newline to what is printed, you need `use feature 'say';` at the beginning.

Always start your programs with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.

Comment: thanks, I never knew you could redirect STDOUT. it strikes me that technically you could still use `warn` to print to the console though

Comment: @beasy One of the standard docs for background on this is [I/O redirection (bash)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). But note that modules make that much easier. For example, I can readily find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045913/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501427/4653379)

Comment: @beasy Indeed. The warn goes to STDERR, a different stream (fd 2). That stream does come out on the console unless it is redirected as well. When I have STDOUT redirected for a program I usual also redirect STDERR (in the exact same manner), and usually to a different file. This is because such programs run unattended, out of cron or other tools, and I need all their output in files. Then the program can check in the end whether the STDERR-file is emtpy, and if it isn't it sends me an email warning me that there were errors (otherwise it deletes the file).